# $rows doesnt work anymore

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried to upgrade my working mysql script to mysqli but I'm having some problems with my $rows variable.. $rows doesn't return anything anymore.. echo $rows; returns blanc.

here's my code:\

```
<?php
    $host = "***";
    $user = "***";
    $pwd = "***";
    $db_name = "name";

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name)or die("cannot connect"); 



    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM foto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    //var_dump($sql);


    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
       echo "<img class='littleshow'"."id='foto".$rows[$id]."'src='".$rows[$foto]."' onclick='Bigscreen(this)'></img>";
    } 
?>
```

thanks for helping :)

Comment: $id and $foto variable holds ur db column name?

Comment: yea.. for example $id contains '1' and $foto contains 'pic/fotoname.jpg'

Comment: you just mentioned **values**, not **names**

Comment: it will not work in that way. You have to mention column name in these variable you need to use direct column name like `$rows['id']` or `$rows['foto']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables $id and $foto are not defined anywhere, change it to this and you will see there is output echoed, assuming there are rows returned by the query. ($rows[$id] = $rows['id'])

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo "<img class='littleshow'"."id='foto".$rows['id']."'src='".$rows['foto']."' onclick='Bigscreen(this)'></img>";
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked :D, i defines them in my previous script as variables.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $rows;` returns blank means there was no rows returned by the query.

it's also worth to set full error reporting in PHP to see possible mistakes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: It's connected to the database and it worked when i used mysql.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it have connected in the past. I am talking of how it works, not how it worked somewhere else long time ago. Either you have no idea what $row contains, or - if it really blank - the the query returned nothing.